# Getting crash when trying to set General Link value on sitecore

Tags: sitecore

I am working on a template that have a General Link field, when I am trying to set the Insert link on Sitecore Content Editor I am getting below crash:

[image]

I am working on Sitecore 8.0 (rev.150121)

Even though the other General link options is working fine:

- Insert media link
- Insert external link
- Insert anchor
- Insert email
- Insert JavaScript

I added a new field to the same template as a general link filed as well and it is working fine even for the Insert link option.

when I view the Raw value for the item I found that the link had a default value set to "" when I removed it and save all is working fine, the other testing link that I added do not have this default value, and the field on the template itself do not have such value or any default value.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This is a duplication of the question found on the Sitecore StackExchange [here](https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/questions/1281/exception-thrown-when-trying-to-set-general-link-value). Just to avoid any open question, here is the answer as provided in the same question:

The issue you reported was fixed in Sitecore Experience Platform 8.0 rev. 150621 (8.0 Update-4) and you can upgrade your solution to address the problem.

Please take a look at the reference number 416281 in Sitecore CMS release notes on for additional details on the fix: https://dev.sitecore.net/Downloads/Sitecore%20Experience%20Platform/8%200/Sitecore%20Experience%20Platform%2080%20Update4/Release%20notes

If upgrade is not an option for you, we suggest you implement the following workaround to resolve the issue on your current solution:

Place the attached Sitecore.Support.416281 assembly to the \bin folder of your solution;

Open /sitecore/system/Field types/Link Types/General Link item in the Core database;

Clean up its Control field;

Put Sitecore.Support.416281 in the Assembly field and Sitecore.Support.Link in the Class field;

Save changes.

Please download the assembly : https://www.dropbox.com/s/hl7ho6wmnca8u2y/Sitecore.Support.416281.dll?dl=0